# jQuery resizable with dynamic minHeight

Tags: javascript, jquery, resizable

I'm using the resizable function from jQuery. I'm trying to use a dynamic minHeight for the resizable div.

This is what I tried so far:

```
$( ".header-area" ).resizable({
        handles: 's',
        maxHeight: 500,
        minHeight: $("#headerMinHeight").val();
    });
```

**Update**

The solution:

```
$( ".header-area" ).resizable({
        handles: 's',
        maxHeight: 500,
        start: function()
        {
            $(".header-area").resizable("option","minHeight", $("#headerMinHeight").val());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you'd set the dynamic variable outside of the resizable function?

```
var headerMinHeight = $("#headerMinHeight").val();
$( ".header-area" ).resizable({
    handles: 's',
    maxHeight: 500,
    minHeight: headerMinHeight
});
```